# Jquery.flip не работает

Tags: jquery

Здравствуйте,

помогите пожалуйста понять, почему не работает скрипт.
Все подключаю верно - не реагирует.

Подскажите пожалуйста, что не правильно и как при повороте блока показывать другое изображение.

**UPD:** Как выяснилось, скрипт не работал, по причине нахождения вызова после всех других скриптов в файле script.js. Так, что оснается только понять, как на обратной стороне отображать другую фотографию.

**[Вот код.](http://jsfiddle.net/Alex83/6Z4jj/2/)**

Спасибо

*На jsfiddle плагины не подключал.*

Comment: пути точно верные прописал?

Comment: подключите к своему fidle jquery и flip плагин, почему за вас кто-то это делать должен ?

Comment: @eicto, подключил.

Comment: не вижу, нажмите update и обновите ссылку в вопросе.

Comment: Прошу прощения. Сказывается третья бессонная ночь. Исправил.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Есть же параметр onEnd,

вот так примерно использовать:

```
       $(".card").flip({
             direction:"rl",
             onEnd: function() {
                 $(".card img").attr('src',nextimg(images));
           }
    });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/6Z4jj/3/